# Write to a windows network share from unix

Tags: java, networking, share

The following code works like a charm in eclipse under windows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        String filePath = "\\\\myserver\\dir";
        String fileName = "myFile.txt";
        FileWriter myFileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath + File.separator + fileName); 
        BufferedWriter myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(myFileWriter);
        myBufferedWriter.write("test");
        myBufferedWriter.close();       
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I want to run this code from a unix machine in the same network. The program runs, but does not write my file or throws an exception. Any ides ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that destination unix machine has Samba installed you might want to try the following library:

http://jcifs.samba.org/

You would need a username and password though.

```
try {
        String filePath = "myserver/dir";
        String fileName = "myFile.txt";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "password";
        // URL: smb://user:passwd@host/share/filname
        SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream("smb://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + filePath
                + File.separator + fileName);
        out.write("test".getBytes());
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This would also work with a windows machine as the destination if the server is configured as an SMB server.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Unix/Linux this is not the right path

```
String filePath = "\\\\myserver\\dir";
```

I suggest to check such path exist, and 99% chances you will not have permission to create them. It would be more or less

> String filePath = "/usr/xx/";

Creating folder:

```
File temp = new File("temp");
boolean test = temp.mkDir();
```

Comment: I figured this much - how could I address this problem ?

Comment: Under *nix, you can only create such folder structure if and only if you have sudo access, which is not given in corporate world. so just check where exactly that needs to be created

Comment: The problem is that this share is on a third unix machine, which is completely independant. There must be a way to access this share like windows does ?

Comment: @Tim, without key, you can't open locker. it's simple. if you have the key (sudo) permission, you will be able to. If not, you can't create.

Comment: Anyway I updated the post on how to create dir, try with that.

Comment: I think we are missing each other's point. I want to write a file into a shared folder. This works when mounted on windows, but not under unix. My question is how to access this folder, knowing that it is not a local path such as /usr/folder, but a remote one. Does it need to be mounted first, and if yes can it be done in Unix ?